# .htaccess quick url fix

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have the following .htaccess script:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# remove enter code here.php; use THE_REQUEST to prevent infinite loops
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ (.*)\.php\ HTTP
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ $1 [R=301]

# remove index
RewriteRule (.*)/index$ $1/ [R=301]

# remove slash if not directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
RewriteRule (.*)/ $1 [R=301]

# add .php to access file, but don't redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^loaidesign.co.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.loaidesign.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It creates URL like: http://www.loaidesign.co.uk/projects.php?project=Wix_Websites is there anyway to get rid of the `.php?project=` and replace it with / so it only says `www.loaidesign.co.uk/projects/Wix_Websites`? Also how to change the "_" to an "-"?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, but I believe that would be:

```
RewriteBase /projects/
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$  $1.php?project=$2
```

Edit: Test it on [this website](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/), it does work.

Comment: But where shall I place it on my current script? can you advice?

Comment: @Leo I've changed it so you can put it anywhere in your script

Comment: Now working, I also have just tested on the website you linked me to

Answer (score 0):

At the end place

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/projects/(.*[^/])$  projects.php?project=$1 [QSA,L]
```

which will rewrite every thing in projects/* to projects.php?project=*

Comment: How can I test it? so the url now shall be: http://www.loaidesign.co.uk/projects/Wix_Websites but it won't work

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/projects\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^project=([a-z_]*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.loaidesign.co.uk/project/%1 [L]
```

This will result in URLs like `http://www.loaidesign.co.uk/project/Wix_Websites`. Tested on http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ and adapted from http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/01/apache-query-string-redirects/

[edit] After numerous comments, I think what you want is the exact opposite. You want to have pretty URLs on yor page (like `/project/foo`) that are then translated to their internal represantation (`?projects.php?project=foo`):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !projects.php
RewriteRule ^project/(.*)$ projects.php?project=$1 [L]
```

[edit2] Together with the first part of my answer one can achieve what you want:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  projects\.php
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^project=([a-z_]*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ project/%1 [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !projects.php
RewriteRule ^project/(.*)$ projects.php?project=$1 [L]
```

It's not perfect as it appends the query string to the prettified URL if an old style URL is entered, but I'll leave that up to you. ;-)

Comment: Also just tested it on that website you linked me to and the outcome is: http://www.loaidesign.co.uk/Wix_Websites but I need project/wix_websites

Comment: The outcome is: http://www.loaidesign.co.uk/projects/Wix_Websites?project=Wix_Websites

Comment: check it for your self: http://www.loaidesign.co.uk/portfolio click on any project and see

Comment: I am not trolling, I really appreciate your time and effort mate

Comment: What do you mean mate? If it is possible we can change what I currently have - please help me buddy!

Comment: Same problem :( I really don't know what to do now

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42740/discussion-between-leo-and-nietonfir)